# When is it NOT necessary to truncate the table when restoring a snapshot (incremental) for Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

When is it NOT necessary to truncate the table when restoring a snapshot (incremental) for Cassandra?

All the different documentation "providers" including the 2nd edition of the Cassandra The Definitive Guide, it says something like this... "If necessary, truncate the table." If you restore without truncating (removing the tombstone), Cassandra continues to shadow the restored data. This behavior also occurs for other types of overwrites and causes the same problem.

If I have an insert only C* keyspace (no upserts and no deletes), do I ever need to truncate before restoring?

The documentation seems to imply that I can delete all of the sstable files from a column family (rm -f /data/*.*), copy the snapshot to /data/, and nodetool refresh.

Is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right - you can restore a snapshot excatly this way. Copy over the sstables, restart the node and you are done. With incremental backups be sure you got all sstables with your data.

What could happen if you have updates and deletes is that after restoring a node or during restoring multiple nodes is that there is stale data available or you could run into problems with tombstones when data was deleted after the snapshot.

The magic with truncating tables is that all data is gone at once and you avoid such problems.

Comment: Indeed... with a restart... but the doc seems to imply that nodetool refresh is all that's needed... which is not true.